# вектор классов - обращение

Tags: c++, классы, vector, вектор

Есть класс, есть вектор векторов этого класса. Как обратиться к элементу класса через вектор векторов?

```
class primer{
public:
string date;
string hello;
};
int main();
primer p[2];
vector<vector<primer>> p1;
vector<primer> p2;
string q = "qwerty";
p[0].date = "22.01";
p[0].hello = "asd";
p2.push_back(p);
p1.push_back(p2);
p[1].date = "22.19";
p[1].hello = "qwerty";
p2.push_back(p);
p1.push_back(p2);
```

И после обращения необходимо найти в векторе p1 строку которая равна q и вывести все элементы этого класса, которому принадлежит найденная строка

Comment: a конструкция `p1[0][0].date` уже не работает?

Comment: `p1[i][j].hello` ... можно ручным перебором, можно алгоритмами.

Comment: если выводить `cout << p1[0][0].date;` компилятор ругается

Comment: Почитайте о том, как должен выглядеть [mcve]

Comment: как обратиться к элементам такого вектора, чтобы можно было выводить содержимое на экран `cout << p1[0][0].date;` не работает

Answer (score 0):

Чтоб **компилировалось**, нужно так:

```
int main()
{
    primer p[2];
    vector<vector<primer>> p1;
    vector<primer> p2;
    string q = "qwerty";
    p[0].date = "22.01";
    p[0].hello = "asd";
    p2.push_back(p[0]);
    p1.push_back(p2);
    p[1].date = "22.19";
    p[1].hello = "qwerty";
    p2.push_back(p[1]);
    p1.push_back(p2);
}
```

Но вот то ли это, что вы хотите - разбирайтесь сами :) Здесь у вас первый вектор в векторе - из одного элемента, второй - из двух...

Дальше просто используйте цикл типа

```
for(const auto& p2: p1)
{
     // Ищем в p2 строку, если есть - выводим p2
     // Типа перебираем все строки в p2
     //      for(auto x: p2) 
     //          if (x.date == q)  // если строка есть 
     //              for(auto y: p2) cout << y.date;  // выводим весь p2
     // (Набросок на коленке, не для компиляции :))
}
```

Или вот, даже компилируемый :) -

```
int main()
{
    primer p[2];
    vector<vector<primer>> p1;
    vector<primer> p2;
    string q = "qwerty";
    p[0].date = "22.01";
    p[0].hello = "asd";
    p2.push_back(p[0]);
    p1.push_back(p2);
    p[1].date = "22.19";
    p[1].hello = "qwerty";
    p2.push_back(p[1]);
    p1.push_back(p2);
    for(const auto& p: p1)
    {
        for(const auto& r: p)
            if (r.hello == q)
                for(const auto& v: p)
                    cout << v.date << " " << v.hello << "\n";
    }
}
```

Правда, красивее все же через алгоритмы стандартной библиотеки...

Comment: да, спасибо, это я исправил, но вот с выводом проблема, как я уже выше написал

Comment: См. набросок кода в ответе

Comment: Все равно не компилируется почему - то. Ругается на << после cout

Comment: Вот, смотрите: https://ideone.com/qxpB6i